# Virtual inheritance and uniform initialization in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, gcc, c++14

Following up on [this question about multiple (virtual) inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914076/initialization-list-bug-in-gcc), I'd like to inquire about a simple MWE that makes **g++ 5.2.0** upset whereas **clang++ 3.6.2** handles it just fine, with no complaints at all, even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` set. So here's the MWE:

```cpp
class Z {};
class A : virtual Z { protected: A() {} };
class B : virtual Z { protected: B() {} };
class C : A, B { public: C() : A{}, B{} {} };
int main() { C c{}; return 0; }
```

Unlike clang++, g++ complains like this:

```
gccodd.c++: In constructor ‘C::C()’:
gccodd.c++:2:34: error: ‘A::A()’ is protected
 class A : virtual Z { protected: A() {} };
                                  ^
gccodd.c++:4:39: error: within this context
 class C : A, B { public: C() : A{}, B{} {} };
                                       ^
gccodd.c++:3:34: error: ‘B::B()’ is protected
 class B : virtual Z { protected: B() {} };
                                  ^
gccodd.c++:4:39: error: within this context
 class C : A, B { public: C() : A{}, B{} {} };
                                       ^
```

Replacing the uniform initialization in C's constructor with the old form works fine though and both clang++ and g++ are happy with the following:

```cpp
class C : A, B { public: C() : A(), B() {} };
```

This yields the two obvious options:

1. The code violates the standard in some way, making the outcome undefined (i.e., any outcome would be acceptable).
2. One of the two compilers has a bug related to uniform initialization and multiple + virtual inheritance.

If it were a matter of voting, (1) might win, because **icpc 15.0.0** says the following:

```
gccodd.c++(4): error #453: protected function "A::A()" (declared at line 2) is not accessible through a "A" pointer or object
  class C : public virtual A, public virtual B { public: C() : A{}, B{} {} };
                                                                ^

gccodd.c++(4): error #453: protected function "B::B()" (declared at line 3) is not accessible through a "B" pointer or object
  class C : public virtual A, public virtual B { public: C() : A{}, B{} {} };
                                                                     ^
```

So, is it (1) or (2)? And if it's the former case, then what's wrong with my MWE?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. No reason to think that there'd be UB here.

Comment: VC++ 14.0 compiles it fine too, although IntelliSense complaines about it.

Comment: GCC is buggy when it comes to [aggregate-initialization of base classes in a mem-initializer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c60d42406381caa).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Interesting, it looks like it's trying to make a temporary and then do a copy. That'd also explain the OP's errors.

Answer (score 5):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as
>   follows:
>  (3.1) — If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a
>   single element of type *cv* `U` [..]
>  (3.2) — Otherwise, if `T` is a
>   character array [..] 
> (3.3) — Otherwise, if T is an aggregate,
>   aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1). 
> (3.4) — **Otherwise, if
>   the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a
>   default constructor, the object is value-initialized.**

`A` and `B` both have base classes and hence aren't aggregates. So the fourth bullet point applies. And thus we have the exact same effect as if we had used `()`:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   `()`, shall be value-initialized.

Any compiler yielding different results with those initializers cannot be  conforming.

§11.4, which handles access to `protected` members, does not mention anything related to the form of initialization. However, concerning initialization of bases in a mem-initializer in the constructor, §11.4 is defective at the moment as mentioned by CWG issue [**#1883**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1883).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the exact part of the standard describing this case. So it appears that the Intel compiler / "composer" takes its GCC compatibility somewhat too seriously, implementing GCC bugs as well. :-) As for bugs in the standard, I've recently spotted [this question about references and uniform initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509603/why-cant-i-initialize-a-reference-in-an-initializer-list-with-uniform-initializ). Basically a transposition of 2 bullet points in the standard opened up a 3-year window of buggy (in a sense) compilers.