# Why does uniform initialization in C++11 behave weirdly with virtual base classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Right now, I am learning the features of Inheritance in C++ and wanted to test out the recently learnt concept of Virtual Base classes.
I tried the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int m_value;
    string m_caller;
public:
    A(int p_value, string p_caller) : m_value{p_value}, m_caller{p_caller}
    {
        cout<<"Instantiating A via "<<m_caller<<endl;
    }
};

class B : virtual public A
{
private:
    int m_value;
public:
    B(int p_value1,int p_value2) : A{p_value1,"B"}, m_value{p_value2}
    {
        cout<<"Instantiating B."<<endl;
    }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C(int p_value1,int p_value2) : A{p_value1,"C"}, B(p_value1, p_value2)
    {
        cout<<"Instantiating C."<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c1(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note the `B(p_value1, p_value2)` in the constructor of class C. This gave me the desired output:

```
Instantiating A via C
Instantiating B.
Instantiating C.
```

But, the moment I changed it to `B{p_value1, p_value2}`, I got the following output:

```
Instantiating A via C
Instantiating A via B
Instantiating B.
Instantiating C.
```

I tried looking for the answer, but all the answers I got quoted some C++ standards. Being a beginner in OOPs, I am looking for a simpler explanation for this behaviour.
Thanks a lot!

P.S. I am using C::B in Windows with compiler g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Fyi, clang++ 3.7 does not exhibit the behavior you're describing. Both versions emit the same output (the first).

Comment: You're calling the copy constructor in the second case.

Comment: @UpAndAdam The most derived class is responsible for initializing virtual base classes, the code wouldn't compile if the OP didn't call `A`'s constructor directly. And what is this about *passing in converted string literals as though they are ints*?

Comment: nm, read part of his code wrong, redacting..

Comment: More fyi, g++ v6.1 exhibits the behavior you describe as well ([**see here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba3f1b30ad557d7c)), but clang++ 3.8 does not ([**see here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69d2d24974c4fb26)).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for pointing it out! Guess this and a few other reasons I found on Google are good enough for me to should shift to using clang :)

Comment: @lorro I couldn't get how the copy constructor is called. As far as I understand a copy constructor is a member function which initializes an object using another object of the same class. I clearly haven't done that

Comment: I think you may be experiencing a similar/same issue [to **this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914076/initialization-list-bug-in-gcc), which has a variety of assessments (including a claim this works in gcc 4.9.2). Take that for what it's worth. It also mentioned [a **bug**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55922) already filed against gcc about this.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I suppose that's it then! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a compiler bug in g++.

In C++14 (N4140) section [dcl.init.list], the definition of list initialization is (edited for conciseness):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of std::initializer_list, [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution. If a narrowing conversion is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.
> - [...]

The first 3 points don't apply: `B` is not an aggregate (aggregate cannot have base classes), the initializer list does have elements, `B` is not a specialization of `std::initializer_list`.

The fourth point does apply because overload resolution matches `B{p_value1, p_value2}` to the constructor `B(int, int)` according to [over.match.list]/1.2:

> If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

It follows from the last quote that `B(whatever)` and `B{whatever}` should behave identically.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks :)